# my location google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I used this code to display my location and it works. The problem is when I navigate in the map it directly takes me back to my location!

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
                    latitude = arg0.getLatitude();
                    longtude = arg0.getLongitude();
                    myLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longtude);
                    CameraUpdate center=
                            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation);
                        CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);

                        map.moveCamera(center);
                        map.animateCamera(zoom);
                }
               });
```

Also I want to save latitude and longtude  for more uses but it gives me null when I'm out of the listener?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your GPS will disable your location will be null. So must ensure that GPS will be On.

Comment: To get Lat, Long..GPS not must required....You can also get from NetWork provider.

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas I know it but when GPS is disabled network provider will work but before that need to save last location.

Answer (score 0):

**That is happening because you are moving the camera in side onMyLocationChange( ).when ever this method is triggered it will take you that particular location no matter where you are navigating .for second query you can use SharedPreferences to store those values when they are not null **